# Validar sello digital SAT México

Tags: c#

Intento validar el sello digital de un Comprobante fiscal Digital por Internet (CFDi) México.

La documentación SAT dice:

> "Desencriptar el contenido del atributo sello usando el certificado incluido en el atributo "Certificado". Generar la cadena original del comprobante. Aplicar el algoritmo de digestión SHA-256. El resultado de la digestión debe ser igual al resultado de la desencripción del sello."

Tengo los siguientes datos y el siguiente código, pero cert.PublicKey hace referencia a que es obsoleto y no he podido actualizar esa línea de código:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

string version = "3.3"; // Obtenido del XML
string certificado = "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"; // Obtenido del XML
string selloBase64 = "JyjYN34FpmYU6COMxA689FEB7kZBlu3xx6BzSBx7MuwvqsgH33hxj6dt0KXjKlwP7frAiHqZeFhk7IK6DDqCFLljA3D/Aq+FtcxCSi5+N3EHTTBBUmcWggmyAEyTgWHRN5m/ARusbXOZWlXf2CV8hRQycTZ9lJ/9WMgmDiVbaXHXg/q2B4eiByrQ/eeOThQjNuiyc1H96GydiHfZiVIsrPBfgD4uirZSuXbBzg9CewGP0uFpp170HUof2kCzpjkaL6VNJrX5LK22Jqsxs/ch04itn6dJkyNWpZQgign0OxyUA8/62pf1rSjZd8Dot/WYOCgH4N2PTiqLbInlq/1KhQ=="; // Obtenido del XML
string cadenaOriginal = "||3.3|064F|11842|2022-07-14T16:55:18|99|00001000000509243980|120 DIAS NETO|12536.25|MXN|14542.05|I|PPD|86000|RAC870406P40|RODAMIENTOS Y ACCESORIOS S.A. DE C.V.|601|IPB7405157E6|INGENIO PRESIDENTE BENITO JUAREZ, S.A. DE C.V.|G03|31181700|S/M00184735|1|H87|Pza|SM-CTL-7 S/M0 CORDON ATEFLONADO CAJA CON 5KILOS|8156.25|8156.25|8156.25|002|Tasa|0.160000|1305|31181700|SUMA0196046|2|H87|Pza|SM-LAIC-5 SUMA EMPAQUE D/ASBESTO1/8X60X60 C/INSERCION D/MALLA|2190|4380|4380.00|002|Tasa|0.160000|700.80|002|Tasa|0.160000|2005.80|2005.80||"; // Obtenido del XML y el XSLT

byte[] sello = Convert.FromBase64String(selloBase64);


X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certificado));
RSACryptoServiceProvider verificador = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
HashAlgorithm algoritmoHash = null;
byte[] hashCadenaOriginal = null;
bool selloValido = false;
switch (version)
{
    case "3.2":
        algoritmoHash = SHA1.Create();
        hashCadenaOriginal = algoritmoHash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cadenaOriginal));
        selloValido = verificador.VerifyHash(hashCadenaOriginal, "SHA1", sello);
        break;
    case "3.3":
        algoritmoHash = SHA256.Create();
        hashCadenaOriginal = algoritmoHash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cadenaOriginal));
        selloValido = verificador.VerifyHash(hashCadenaOriginal, "SHA256", sello);
        break;
}

if (selloValido)
{
    // Factura válida
}
```

> Soy de profesión Contador Público, pero aficionado a la programación; aprendiendo C#, me parece bueno.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Gracias por las cortesias, pero en este sitio tratamos de centrar la pregunta en solamente la pregunta, para no distraer. No probaste nada de como desencriptar el sello contra el certificado, no?

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código y a mi si me funciono, si pudieras proporcionar la configuración del ambiente. Yo utilicé de Framework ".NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile" y el compilador "C# 5.0".

Comment: Me late que el SAT trabaja con `.net Framework` y aquí Diego Almeida está con `.net core`

Comment: La propiedad PublicKey.Key está marcada como obsoleta a partir de .NET 6. El empleo de esta API en el código genera una advertencia SYSLIB0027 en tiempo de compilación. estoy trabajando con .NET 6.